# How to solve the system error when file is not found on specified location?

Tags: performance, android-studio

whenever i tried to build the project an error occur (C:\Users\apex.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.6-all\bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg\gradle-4.6-all.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)
) 
i do not know how to solve this issu, is there anyone who can help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Is that file in the specified directory?

Comment: i have not changed any file directory i have created my first program

Comment: the error is telling you that a certain file is missing. you should definitely check if its there first, whether its named differently, or located somewhere else.